# Determine whether the sequence converge or diverge

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence is

$$a_{n+1} = 2a_n - 1$$

and

$$a_1 = 1$$

The sequence should be

$$\{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...\}$$

and I get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 1$$

However
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n = s = \infty$$

So is the sequence convergent or divergent? In other words, how do I judge the sequence?

Comment: What is $s_n$?  You have only defined what $a_n$ is and have not told us anything about $s_n$... is it the sequence of partial sums or what?  Keep in mind the difference between the words **sequence** and **series**

Comment: It is the sequence of partial sum. s1 = 1, s2 = 2, s3 = 3, ..., sn = n.

Comment: The *sequence* $a_n$ is convergent.  The *sequence* $s_n$, i.e. the *series* $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, is divergent.  These two facts are not in conflict with one another.  When you say "the sequence is divergent/convergent" and you have talked about multiple sequences, you need to be clear which you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle a_{n + 1} - 1 = 2\left(a_{n} - 1\right) \implies
a_{n + 1} = 2^{n}\left(a_{1} - 1\right) = 0\quad\mbox{because}\ a_{1} = 1$.

> In *general*, the sequence *diverges* whenever $\displaystyle a_{1} \not= 1$.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $a_n$ is convergent, as you pointed out, because the limit is $1$.

The sequence of partial sums, $s_n$, diverges, but this does not mean that $a_n$ does not converge.

Answer (score -1):

**If** the seq. is convergent, then $\lim_n a_{n+1}=\lim_n a_{n}$. Now for this limit, let $x=\lim a_{n+1}=\lim a_n$, then

$$
x=2x-1
$$
has solution $x=1$. Can you now prove that for every $\epsilon>0, \exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $\forall m>n$ we have $|a_m-1|<\epsilon$?

Comment: "If a sequence is convergent then for big enough $n$, $a_{n+1}=a_n$" is false.  The sequence $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ converges to zero but there exists no $n$ such that $a_n=a_{n+1}$.

Comment: Im refering to that $\lim a_n = \lim a_{n+1}$ @jmoravitz